# How to "log" in Amazon Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk

I've deployed an application and enabled cloudwatch. The issue is that stderr from the application running is not displayed in cloudwatch? How am I supposed to view the logs generated by my app? All I see are the logs from the builder and nginx/proxy in front of my app.

```
/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Default-Environment/var/log/eb-activity.log
/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Default-Environment/var/log/nginx/access.log
/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Default-Environment/var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Comment: Beanstalk log viewer is pretty rudimentary anyway. Just log somewhere else (loggly, graylog, splunk, logentries, kibana... there's about a million better options than the Beanstock tool.)

Answer (score 2):

Go logging is broken on beanstalk. THat's because cloudwatch doesn't collect the web logs (i.e. web-1.error.log) . You can see it on aws docs...it collects only the ebl and nginx/proxy logs. As this great cloud is not open source nobody but Amazon can ever fix it(if they decide to do so).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html

Comment: now they collects `/var/log/web-1.log`, `/var/log/web-1.error.log`